# Capture single channel in Audacity with PreSonus VSL 1818

Tags: audio, microphone, sound-card, audacity

I am trying a ProSonus VSL 1818 audio box for one microphone. I installed the ProSonus Universal Control. QuickTime captures sound out of the box. Audacity recognizes the device, with VSL 1818 as a device and is able to capture sound if I select 8 channels. Then I have to delete the other tracks with each new take. I would like to capture the only channel in use, but with channel `1 mono`, Audacity captures no sound.

[image: AudioBox with Audacity]

How can I capture a single channel in use from AudioBox VSL 1818 and Audacity?

Comment: Perhaps Virtual Audio Cable, https://vb-audio.com/Cable/, can direct signals appropriately... let us know if it works here.

Comment: Yes, will do next time I have access to the equipment!